# Model binding for float fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I'm trying to send window's position to the server. But model binding for `top` always fails. My action method is as below:

```
public void winClosed(Window position)
```

And the window model:

```
public class Window
{
    public decimal Left { get; set; }
    public double Top { get; set; }
}
```

In this picture you can see sample values:

[image: window's positioin]

And finally the JavaScript code:

```
var position = this.wrapper.offset();
$.post("@Url.Action("winClosed", "Home")", position);
```

The first line is relative to Kendo Window. I've already tried `double`, and `float` types in the model.

Comment: Is your ajax method hit the controller and do you write the JavaScript at the view or an JavaScript file?

Comment: Yes, it hits the action and I'll get the `left` just fine. And this call is from the `_Layout`.

Comment: What is the culture on the server (is the decimal separator a `.` (dot) or a `,` (comma)?

Comment: Culture is `fa-IR`, I don't know the separator. But it seems to be `.`

Comment: I think the decimal separator for farsi-Iran is `/`. Try initially setting `var position = { top: 93/3666, left: 210 };` to see if it binds.

Comment: Please post the answer Stephen so I can select it. I'm changing the separator like this: `position['top'] = position['top'].toString().replace('.', '/');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decimal separator for your culture (fa-IR) is `/` (forward slash) character. You will need to replace the `.` character with a `/` character. For example

```
var offset = this.wrapper.offset();
var l = offset.left.toString().replace('.', '/');
var t = offset.top.toString().replace('.', '/');
$.post("@Url.Action("winClosed", "Home")", {left: l, top: t });
```

Comment: I just figured out that there is a funny thing about kendo window, its `position` accepts just `int`! So you can simply use `parseInt`.